# MailKit does not find message ID

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

I am currently migrating from [OpenPop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/) to [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).

I have a unit test that loads a string into a MimeMessage like this:

```
var emailText = @"
X-MDAV-Processed: mx1.footechnology.com.au, Mon, 30 Mar 2015 12:54:30 +1100
Return-path: <do-not-reply@baz.com.au>
Received: from mail2.baz.com.au (mail2.baz.com.au [220.157.74.146])
    by mx1.footechnology.com.au (mx1.footechnology.com.au)
    (MDaemon PRO v11.0.3)
    with ESMTP id md50005410292.msg
    for <faxes@foobar.com.au>; Mon, 30 Mar 2015 12:54:29 +1100
Authentication-Results: mx1.footechnology.com.au
    spf=neutral smtp.mail=do-not-reply@baz.com.au;
    x-ip-ptr=pass dns.ptr=mail2.baz.com.au (ip=220.157.74.146);
    x-ip-helo=pass smtp.helo=mail2.baz.com.au (ip=220.157.74.146);
    x-ip-mail=pass smtp.mail=do-not-reply@baz.com.au (ip=220.157.74.146)
Received-SPF: none (mx1.footechnology.com.au: do-not-reply@baz.com.au does not
    designate permitted sender hosts)
    x-spf-client=MDaemon.PRO.v11.0.3
    receiver=mx1.footechnology.com.au
    client-ip=220.157.74.146
    envelope-from=<do-not-reply@baz.com.au>
    helo=mail2.baz.com.au
X-Spam-Processed: mx1.footechnology.com.au, Mon, 30 Mar 2015 12:54:29 +1100
    (not processed: sender do-not-reply@baz.com.au in exclude file)
X-MDPtrLookup-Result: pass dns.ptr=mail2.baz.com.au (ip=220.157.74.146) (mx1.footechnology.com.au)
X-MDHeloLookup-Result: pass smtp.helo=mail2.baz.com.au (ip=220.157.74.146) (mx1.footechnology.com.au)
X-MDMailLookup-Result: pass smtp.mail=do-not-reply@baz.com.au (ip=220.157.74.146) (mx1.footechnology.com.au)
X-MDDK-Result: neutral (mx1.footechnology.com.au)
X-MDDKIM-Result: neutral (mx1.footechnology.com.au)
X-MDSPF-Result: none (mx1.footechnology.com.au)
X-Rcpt-To: faxes@foobar.com.au
X-MDRcpt-To: faxes@foobar.com.au
X-MDRemoteIP: 220.157.74.146
X-Return-Path: do-not-reply@baz.com.au
X-Envelope-From: do-not-reply@baz.com.au
X-MDaemon-Deliver-To: faxes@foobar.com.au
Received: from melbourne.baz.com.au (melbourne.baz.com.au [118.88.188.238])
    by mail2.baz.com.au (Postfix) with ESMTP id 3E100437181
    for <faxes@foobar.com.au>; Mon, 30 Mar 2015 11:54:17 +1000 (EST)
Received: from baz.com.au (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by melbourne.baz.com.au (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6BA057C07C
    for <faxes@foobar.com.au>; Mon, 30 Mar 2015 12:54:16 +1100 (EST)
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Message-ID : <syd1_did11-1403160784-288657210-5-21314.1403160831@medora2.syd1.colo.j2noc.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=""_----------=_1301450056175850""
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: MIME::Lite 3.01 (F2.72; B3.04; Q3.03)
Date: Mon, 30 Mar 2015 01:54:16 UT
From: ""Baz"" <do-not-reply@baz.com.au>
To: ""Foo Bar"" <fax@foobar.com.au>

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_----------=_1301450056175850
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Length: 1133
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the content of the message.

--_----------=_1301450056175850
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=""fax-20110330125416.pdf""
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/pdf; name=""fax-20110330125416.pdf""

JVBERi0xLjEgDSXi48/TDQoxIDAgb2JqDTw8IA0vVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZyAN

--_----------=_1301450056175850--
";

            var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(emailText));
            var message = MimeMessage.Load(stream);

            Console.WriteLine("Text body:" + message.TextBody);
            Console.WriteLine("Html body:" + message.HtmlBody);
            Console.WriteLine("Date:" + message.Date);
            Console.WriteLine("MessageId:" + message.MessageId);
            Console.WriteLine("From:" + message.From.Mailboxes.First().Address);
            Console.WriteLine("To:" + message.To.Mailboxes.First().Address);
```

Whilst the message is successfully parsed, the MessageId header is not found. OpenPop could find the MessageId in the email. Why does MailKit fail? Is the message id header somehow considered invalid and thrown away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the extra space before the ':' char:

`Message-ID : <syd1_did11-1403160784-288657210-5-21314.1403160831@medora2.syd1.colo.j2noc.com>`

Comment: I've just [committed a fix](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/commit/12d31d9c5c695f69734a14e607c88d50978a6e91) to MimeKit to handle spaces after the field name, so the next release of MimeKit (1.0.10?) will handle this.